# JNLP - application-desc vs applet-desc - is one better than the other when not running in browser?

Tags: java, swing, deployment, jnlp, java-web-start

I have an applet which I no longer want to run in the browser - but in stead want to run as a downloadable, auto-updating, oflineable Java application via JNLP.

I do not want to maintain the ability to run it as an applet.

I have no problem with either wrapping the existing applet in a JFrame and a main-menthod, or simply rewriting it and replacing the init() and others all together.

But my question is:
Are there any advantages or disadvantages to to using  application-desc vs applet-desc?

Comment: BTW  +1 for *"I have an applet which I no longer want to run in the browser"*  Free the GUI (from the browser wrapper)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first advantage of converting to `JFrame` based, is that you have immediate control of the top level container for things like:

- menus
- look & feel
- default close operation
- location
- size by `pack()` (hooRAY!)
- ..

Go with `applicaton-desc` for a free floating deployment.  But don't put the applet in a frame, instead put the applet content into a panel, and put the panel into the frame (or applet, or window, or..).